# get data from input when new window open

Tags: python, list, forms, get

can someone help me get the data from this form?

i need it to open the new window with the info from the forms contact and vendor (makeformconf) separately.

when i click the button to open the new window and get the value it print the fields names but itdont get the inputs

```
fieldsconf = ('field1:','field2:','field3:','field4:')



def makeformconf(mainwind, fieldsconf):
   entries = {}
   for field in fieldsconf:
      row = Frame(frmConf)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)

      lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field + " ", anchor='w')
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)

      entconf = Entry(row,width="47")
      entconf.insert(0, "")
      entconf.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries[fieldsconf] = entconf
   return entries




def newwin():
   newwingo = Toplevel(mainwind)
   newwingo.title("titulo")
   newwingo.geometry("500x200")
   Label(newwingo, text="2").pack()

   for field in fieldsconf:
      row = Frame(newwingo)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)

      lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field + " ", anchor='w')
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)

      labc = Label(row, width=15, text=entconf.get(0), anchor='w')
      labc.pack(side=LEFT)


if __name__ == '__main__':
     entconf = makeformconf(mainwind, fieldsconf)


btngo = Button(statfrm, text='Go',bg='white', fg='orange', command=newwin)
btngo.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5, anchor='w')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   mainwind.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance